# How to draw a Histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a set of around 35000 data. These data are the signal strengths received only from a single location for different time interval of time. I want to plot a Histogram using these data. My X-axis will give the information about "Signal Strengths" and my Y-axis will give the information about "Probability". My histogram will consists of different bars which will give information about the signal strength and probabilities.

For example, suppose I have the following data

```
a= [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
```

How can I plot the graph using data at X-axis and Probability at Y-axis? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the functions `hist`, `histogram`, `histogram2` depending on your matlab version...? Or even typing `doc histogram` into matlab?

Comment: Yes I have but I am unable to figure out how to add the probabilities from 0 to 1 in this case.

Comment: You just want to normalize your histogram values so that they sum up to 1, isn't that right?

Comment: Yes I think normalization is required. It will be helpful if you give an example of it please.

Comment: I suggest that you [**R**ead **T**hat **F**ine **M**anual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html): `h = histogram(x,'Normalization','probability')`

Comment: @AndrasDeak. "Fine". Sugarcoated that one nicely...

Comment: @StewieGriffin, this should be a family-friendly site, this is the only way I can hope to not get my comment deleted;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine if you don't want to use some predefined functions:

`una=unique(a);
normhist=hist(a,size(unique(a),2))/sum(hist(a));
figure, stairs(una,normhist)`

`Una` has only the unique values of `a`, `normhist` is now between `0` and `1` and it's the probability of occurring of the individual signal because you divide it by the number of elements included in the data.

Comment: Note that just because it's between 0 and 1 it doesn't become a probability. For that you need `sum(numhist)==1`. But this just means that you should divide by `sum(hist(a))` rather than the `max`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

I will fix the answer now. I was just looking in terms of normalization of the histogram, not in probability :)

Comment: I am not getting what exactly is happening in line 2. If you can explain it then it will be helpful.

Comment: So, take the example the data set you posted above.
You have: 6 ones, 3 twos, 9 threes, 3 fours, 1 five and the rest of them are sixes. You have a total of 33 data dots. Sum(hist(a)) == size(a,2), so of all the data points you have a probability of 6/33 that "1" has occurred, 2/33 that "2" has occurred, and so on... You achieve this for all the data points if you divide the entire histogram by 33, which actually is sum(hist(a)). The hist(a,size(unique(a),2)) is here so it would calculate the histogram only in the points that are unique in the data set, which is 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 in this example.

Comment: You don't need to use unique(a) here actually, since it's already calculated in the first line. You can use "una" here instead of the unique(a).

Comment: not sure if    stairs(una,normhist) is the right way to plot the graph because i cant see anything. On the other hand I have around 30,000 data. So is it possible to add the number of bins to the above? Some of the data are like 22.02, 22.14, 22.18,22.37,22.42..etc. So I want to create only one bin (i.e for 22) in this case which will all the above data. Instead of doing 30000 bins I want to use around 100-200 bins in this case to see a clear picture of all. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to calculate the 'hist' function only in 100-200 data points. If that's the question, than cool. If I misunderstood you, I would be glad to help you out if you add more information (code and images) about what happens in the plotting of the histogram. Just edit your question and add your problem at the moment.

Comment: I just saw that I told you to use stairs and I don't know why, since bar gives better looking results. In order to get the same results as histogram, you should write: figure, bar(una,normhist,1), instead of figure, stairs(una,normhist)